# I dont understand this little perl code (if ...)

Tags: perl, if-statement

Can someone explain me this short pearl code?

```
 $batstr2 = "empty"    if( $status2 & 4 );
```

What say the if statement ?

Comment: Which *part* is not understood? The trailing-`if` or the `..` ($status2 & 4) bit? Include details refining the *specific* question in the title.

Comment: `$batstr2 = ($status2 & 4) && "empty"`, well almost. :)

Comment: @mpapec, That's different. Maybe you meant `$batstr2 = $status2 & 4 ? "empty" : $batstr2;` (which is roughly equivalent).

Comment: @ikegami yes of course, that is why I wrote 'almost'.

Comment: @mpapec, What I wrote is almost the same (it's only different if you have magical variables, or if you're considering efficiency). What you wrote isn't remotely similar. It's completely different when `$status2 & 4` is false.

Comment: So which part of 'yes, of course' you have trouble to understand? I can only repeat myself here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a bitwise and - http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Bitwise-And . $status2 is being used as a bit mask and it sets $batstr2 to 'empty' if the bit is set.

Comment: OK ... when I understand it correct: $status = 5 than $batstr2 = "empty" ... right?

Comment: Yes = 5 is 00000101 and 4 is 00000100, bitwise and of the two is 00000100 (4) or true which results in setting 'empty'.

Answer (score 3):

Already answered many times, for the case if you don't know what is the Bitwise And, here is a small example:

```
perl -e 'print "dec\t     bin\t&4\n";printf "%d\t%8b\t%-8b\n", $_, $_, ($_ & 4) for (0..8);'
```

prints:

```
dec      bin    &4
0          0    0       
1          1    0       
2         10    0       
3         11    0       
4        100    100     
5        101    100     
6        110    100     
7        111    100     
8       1000    0
```

as you can see, when the 3rb bit from right is 1 - the `$num & 4` is true.

Answer (score 2):

That's using the `if` as a *statement modifier*. It's roughly the same as

```
if ($status & 4) {
    $batstr2 = "empty";
}
```

and exactly the same as

```
($status & 4) and ($batstr2 = "empty");
```

a variety of constructs can be used as statement modifiers, including: `if, unless, while, until, for, when`. These modifiers can't be stacked (`foo() if $bar for @baz` won't work), you are limited for one modifer per simple statement.

Answer (score 0):

It sets $batstr2 to "empty" if the 3rd least significant bit of $status2 is set - it is a logical AND mask.